# Microcontroller acting as USB host for an audio device

Tags: audio, usb-host

Are there any microcontrollers which are able to act as a USB host for audio devices?
Basically I'd like to create an interface which allows my to connect my USB headset to the analog microphone/headphone jacks of my PC (so it doesn't appear as a separate sound device to the OS).

However, I have no idea if cheap microcontrollers are powerful for that or if there are any microcontrollers which support usb-audio.
Googling wasn't very helpful; most controllers supporting usb-host only support mass storage devices...

Comment: I am somewhat interested in the answers for the questions. I think the act of decoding usb audio on a micro can have lots of uses, more then just sending it to a computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you really like hacking USB, I'd recommend that you either buy an analogue headset or wire some audio jacks onto your existing one.

[LUFA supports USB audio](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/files/LUFA/Doc/090810/html/page_libraryapps.html) in both host and device mode on the USB AVR microcontrollers.

Answer (score 3):

[XMOS devices](https://www.xmos.com/applications/usb-audio) support USB Audio 2.0 for really high audio quality, you could dispense with the PC. They are quite cheap.

Comment: as a USB *host*?

Comment: Yes. Host mode is supported: http://www.xmos.com/multimodedock

Answer (score 3):

The two cheapest USB host devices I know of are [Vinculum VNC2](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/VNC2.htm) (not sure if available yet) and Microchip [PIC24FJ64GB004](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en536118). 
You'll need to look through their USB libraries to see how much work would be needed for audio support.

However for this application I can't help thinking a more analogue solution may be a lot easier, i.e. rip out the digital stuff from the headset.

Comment: Removing the digital stuff would be hard as it's a wireless headset and I doubt there is an easy way to get an analogue signal from the receiver.

Comment: I think the PIC is his way of ripping out the digital stuff without damaging the headset

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about the [MAX3421](http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/3639), but I can't seem to find anyone who's actually used it!  It looks like it might be an easier solution than the Vinculum.